# What iOS 3d engine to use for very simple 3d scene?

Tags: objective-c, ios, 3d

I am planning to develop an iOS app and would love to have some very simple 3d objects the user could interact with either by gestures or gyro. I don't need complex animations or game logic. I have developed simple apps but never used 3d. What frameworks could be  best for such task and does it take a lot to learn and implement?

Answer (score 3):

Cocos engine. Google cocos2D but look for the 3D information. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using OpenGL with GLKit seems to benefit you the most here.

Comment: SceneKit is OSX only, I believe?

Comment: @MattWilding It's in iOS as well.  http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/08/an-introduction-to-scenekit.html

Comment: Yeah that article confirms my suspicions. It says explicitly the SceneKit is OSX only. GLKit exists on iOS, but that's s different story.

Comment: @MattWilding Oops, I never really read the entire thing.  I've always assumed GLKit was the same thing as SceneKit.

Answer (score 1):

I started to use NinevehGL (http://nineveh.gl). It is a very simple framework to load and handle 3D objects for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [OpenGL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) can fit your need.